# solving linear equation - trivial

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

part (a) seems super trivial but I can't seem to get it. Is there a way to find all solutions to the equation? I can only think of a few such as $(1,-1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. Also is how I've written it in a vector form?

Comment: assign any two values of $y$ and $z$, and find $x$

Comment: so (x-y+2z,y,z)?

Comment: The space of solutions is a vector space. You have found already two solutions, therefore any linear combination of them is still a solution. Moreover, the space of solution has dimension 2 (prove it), it follows that if your two generators are linear independent (and they are) they do generate the whole space of solutions.

Comment: @ lohboys:no!  first coordinate is wrong!

Comment: take $y=t$ and $z=s$ to see the solutions are $(2s-t,t,s);s,t \in \Bbb{F}$ and see $\{(2,0,1),(-1,1,0)\}$ forms a basis for this solution space!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR ahh yes! i get it now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $ x= 2y-z$ we have $$v= \begin{bmatrix}
   x\\
y\\
z\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
   2z-y\\
y\\
z\
\end{bmatrix} =y\begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\
1\\
0\ 
\end{bmatrix}+
z\begin{bmatrix}
   2\\
0\\
1\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So 
$$a= \begin{bmatrix}
   -1\\
1\\
0\ 
\end{bmatrix}\;\;{\rm and}\;\;b=
\begin{bmatrix}
   2\\
0\\
1\
\end{bmatrix}$$
generate the set of solution.

Now write TLC for $a$ and $b$ to check if they are LI:

$$ma+nb=0\implies -m+2n=0\;\; {\rm and}\;\;m=0\;\; {\rm and}\;\; n=0$$
so $a$ and $b$ are LI.